# How to create multiplayer / shared AR game with Vuforia?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, photon

I would like to create a shared AR game on Android phones, where I would like to:

1. spawn a cube for each player on an ImageTarget
2. allow them to control the position of their cube
3. allow them to see the movements of all players' cubes

I'm using Vuforia as my AR library and PUN 2 as my networking library. I have no issue synchronizing the positions and rotations of all cubes. However, the cubes do not stay on the ImageTarget properly and "jump" around. On the other hand, if I place my two phones very close together and point them at the ImageTarget at roughly the same angle, the cubes do not jump as much.

This leads me to think that the 2 instances of ARCamera fail to realize that they are pointing at the same ImageTarget from 2 different angles, and instead think that the ImageTarget exists in 2 different orientations at the same time.

Is there any way for me to tell Vuforia that I'm using multiple instances of ARCamera pointing at the same ImageTarget? (Or if my hypothesis is completely wrong, how do I actually make a multiplayer AR game?)

Thanks so much in advance!

p.s. I know the Vuforia forums are a better place to ask this question but unfortunately that forum is not particularly active, so I'm trying my luck here.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by going to the `ARCamera` gameobject, then in the `Vuforia Behavior` component, I changed the `World Center Mode` from DEVICE to FIRST_TARGET. This allows multiple instances of ARCameras to be in different positions.

More info on World Center Mode can be found [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/what-world-center-mode).